# Circuit Construction Kit DC v3.19 won't start

Tags: java

I am trying to start Circuit Construction Kit DC v3.19  because a bit later than that they made an HTML5 version that starts in a browser, and I want the non-HTML version, the one that doesn't use a browser to open.

I see it's a jar file.

So I start it with  `java -jar circuitconstructionkitdcen319.jar` and it gets stuck here, it just hangs, the bar keeps moving left and right but it never finishes loading.

I found it and downloaded it from http://www.brothersoft.com/circuit-construction-kit-(dc-only)-307097.html

I have tried to run it on two different computers and run into the same problem. One computer runs java 1.8, the other also java 8 / 1.8, from https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable   Both run into the same problem.  So I think people will find the problem easy to reproduce.

[image]

Comment: Try an older version of Java. [Around 2010 the version of Java would have been Java 6.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that was just an issue with 3.19 and 3.20 fixed it, and 3.20 is available here

https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/legacy/circuit-construction-kit-dc

That said, now I can start it,

[image]

I see that while the program includes a voltmeter and ammeter, it doesn't even have an Ohmmeter so it's a ridiculously limited learning tool.